# $('').switchClass throwing error in IE8 if the switched class contains color property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've the following css classes

```
.switch-format{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.switch-format1{
  background-color: blue;
}
.switch-format2{
  color: red;
}
```

Using this classes I want to do some animation on the following div

```
<div id="switch-class" class='switch-format' style="margin-top: 5px;">
  Effects - Switch
</div>
```

Following is my jQuery code which will use switchClass to switch the classes at 5 sec interval

```
setTimeout(function() {
  alert('Switch 1');
  jq('#switch-class').switchClass('switch-format', 'switch-format1', 3000);
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
  alert('Switch 2');
  jq('#switch-class').switchClass('switch-format1', 'switch-format2', 3000)
}, 10000);

setTimeout(function() {
  alert('Switch 3');
  jq('#switch-class').switchClass('switch-format2', 'switch-format', 3000)
}, 15000);
```

The first switch happens fine but when the second switch happens it fails in IE8, it works fine in FF3.

The error is 'Invalid Property Value'.

In IE it fails in the following line

```
fx.elem.style[ fx.prop ] = fx.now + fx.unit;
```

with the following values

```
fx.prop = 'borderColor';
fx.now = NaN;
fx.unit = 'px';
fx.elem.style[ fx.prop ] = '';
fx.elem is the div with id 'switch-class';
```

Code To Recreate this issue

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .switch-format{
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .switch-format1{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .switch-format2{
            color: red;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="switch-class" class='switch-format' style="margin-top: 5px;">Effects - Switch</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {
                    alert('Switch 1');
                    $('#switch-class').switchClass('switch-format', 'switch-format1', 3000);
                }, 5000);

        setTimeout(function() {
                    alert('Switch 2');
                    $('#switch-class').switchClass('switch-format', 'switch-format2', 3000)
                }, 10000);

        setTimeout(function() {
                    alert('Switch 3');
                    $('#switch-class').switchClass('switch-format2', 'switch-format', 3000)
            }, 15000);
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested this in IE8.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Forgive me for suggesting this, but try "background:" instead of "background-color". The example provided on jQuery's site doesn't use "-color" in its CSS.

Comment: At the end the error seems to be with this value assignment
fx.elem.style['borderColor' ]='NaNpx';

Comment: Do you have borders set on your divs someplace else in the CSS?

Comment: Try adding `border-color:transparent;` to your classes.

Comment: Check for a border-color, not a border. Note your code: `fx.prop = 'borderColor';`

Comment: First the error come for propery 'borderColor' then for "scrollbarBaseColor"

Comment: Can you put this page online someplace?

Comment: I noticed that you're using the 'jq' object instead of the usual $() or jquery... construction. Have you tried your code in a vanilla HTML page with no other JS libraries other than jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had posted this issue in [jQuery forum](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4807) and they have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may have an invalid border-color value being set that is influencing these elements. You could try to hunt it down (if it exists), or explicitly set a new value for these classes:

```
border-color:transparent;
```

Could be added to your classes to possibly remove this error.

Comment: I've checked for the border-color property, it is not set for the selected div

Comment: What I've found is when jquery is trying to find out the difference in old and new styles somehow it is detecting a change in the border-color.

Answer (score 1):

It is because if there is a color property set then IE/FF will take the same value for border-color and scrollbar-base-color properties even if there is no border or scrollbar-base- set.

We can fix this issue by setting explicit values for these properties in the switching classes. Fixed classes are given below

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .switch-format{
            background-color: yellow;
            border: transparent;
            scrollbar-base-color: white;
        }
        .switch-format1{
            background-color: blue;
            border: transparent;
            scrollbar-base-color: white;
        }
        .switch-format2{
            color: orange;
            border: transparent;
            scrollbar-base-color: white;
        }
    </style>
```

Somehow the value transparent for scrollbar-base-color is not working

Comment: make sure you tick your own answer to close it.

Comment: I try to tick it, but it says 'You can accept your own answer tomorrow.'. So I'll tick it tomorrow.